# Why is the radius of hydrated Na+ greater than that of hydrated K+?

Tags: physical-chemistry, ions

Although $\ce{Na+}$ has ionic radius of 95 pm and an atomic weight of 23, and $\ce{K+}$ has ionic radius of 133 pm and an atomic weight of 39, hydrated $\ce{Na+}$ is larger than hydrated $\ce{K+}$: This is evident from observing that $\ce{Na+}$ moves through a cell membrane with greater difficulty than $\ce{K+}.$

Why is hydrated $\ce{Na+}$ larger in size than hydrated $\ce{K+}?$

Comment: This post needs to be extensively edited - as it stands, it's incomprehensible (for instance, what does ppm have to do with ionic radius?). And what's your question? What are your thoughts?

Comment: @ToddMinehardt Iwould guess that pm = Picometers so .95 Ångstrom and 1.33Å for Na and K. IIRC the actual reason is that the backbone carbonyls of the strands lining the pore can't replace the solvating waters of Na as they are too far away.

Comment: @gilleain do you have a link? I would be interested to read about that

Comment: @orthocresol I don't have any specific references to hand, but 10.1021/ar5002878 looks relevant. Seems like I was remembering one possible model for the selectivity filter, and other filters might use side chains.

Comment: @gilleain. please send the link about it.

Comment: For example, this paper : http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3266868/ says things like "Therefore, unlike K+-channels, the NavAb selectivity filter appears to select and conduct Na+ ions in a mostly hydrated form." So I would have to read more to really answer this...

Comment: Ion transport across cell membranes is quite complicated. If the OP is only interested in solvation of K+ and Na+ they should rephrase the question. In terms of ion channels, both K+ and Na+ have charge +1 but the K+ ion is larger so the water molecules are less tightly bound. This can partly explain why Na+ is transported in hydrated form and K+ is not.